# Can the YN-E3-RT be used, mounted on top of the YN-622C?

Tags: wireless-flash, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo

Using a mix of different older flashes that I'm triggering with Yongnuo YN-622C remote triggers controlled by a YN-622C, I've began looking into the new Yongnuo YN-600EX-RT flashguns. They can be triggered by either another on camera YN-600EX-RT flash or the YN-E3-RT.

Is it possible to combine these new flashes with my old system buy mounting an YN-E3-RT on top of the YN-622C, in turn mounted in the hot shoe of my DSLR? If it does work, can I use E-TTL on the flashes connected to my YN-622C-TX only, the ones connected to my YN-E3-R, both or none of them?

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't switch from 622s to the [YNE3-RX](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yne3-rx-receiver-released/)? Seems more straightforward than stacking.

Comment: @inkista Yes If I stick with the 622s I can control my older speedlites from the camera.

Comment: What specific "older speedlites" are you using?

Comment: @MichaelClark A couple of 430EX II speedlights. I can use optical wireless control, but I usually use them inside of softboxes so radio control is a lot better alternative.

Comment: The YNE3-RX *will* allow you to control your 430EX II flashes from the camera via a YN600EX-RT, Canon 600EX-RT, ST-E3-RT, or YNE3-RT mounted on the camera. It receives the radio signal and then translates the commands to the older flash via the hotshoe connecter attaching it to the flash. See http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yne3-rx-receiver-released/

Comment: @MichaelClark Perfect! That seems just like the device I need. I will not edit this question though. It can still help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stacking an ST-E3-RT on top of a YN-622 transceiver could work, but you'd only have ratio control in eTTL over any pre-MkII Canon EX speedlites connected to YN-622Cs, not manual power level control, and you're still using two separate triggering systems.

A better solution might be to wait and see how the YNE3-RX receivers work out.  Right now, there are some unknowns about them. And they're so new that there aren't a lot of field reports right now. But the assumption is that these will allow full power control over the MkII EX speedlites (and other Canon camera menu-commandable flashes) via an RT master (such as a 600EX-RT, YN-600EX-RT, ST-E3-RT, or YN-E3-RT).

The supported features that are listed are:

- eTTL, M, and MULTI modes
- HSS
- remote shutter release
- PC output for manual-only sync (studio strobes, manual flashes)
- USB port for firmware upgrades
- compatibility with single-contact triggering (manual-only or other-brand flashes)

This is a pretty sparse description. We're *assuming* remote power control and most of the 622 features set.

However, note that on [the promotional announcement the YNE3-RX](http://www.hkyongnuo.com/e-detaily.php?ID=360), that only the following flash models are listed as "compatible" (by which we're assuming hotshoe communication/TTL-type compatible) are:

- Canon 600EX-RT
- 580EX II
- 430EX II
- YN-568EX (II) [which probably means either the Mk I or II]
- YN-565C
- YN-468C (II)
- YN-467C (II)
- YN-465C

Presumption would be that the MkI Canon speedlights would have a similar behavior to that on the YN-622 triggers: only ratio power control in eTTL mode, or possibly manual power level control if the YN-E3-RT dedicated transmitter unit is given a backwards compatibility mode (like the YN-622-TX's) to use eTTL settings to "fake" manual power levels.

Also, [a post from a YN engineer on the POTN board](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?p=16344949) indicates that Supersync is not possible in the RT system.

So, there are a lot of unknowns, and we just have to wait for [actual field reports](http://www.flickr.com/groups/71917374@N00/discuss/72157650312684342/72157650731819517) to let us know for sure what's actually going on.

See:

- http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yne3-rx-receiver-announced/
- http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yne3-rx-receiver-released/

And keep an eye out on the flashhavoc.com blog itself, and probably the [photographyonthe.net thread on the YN-600EX-RT/YN-E3-RT](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1332862) (where elv--the author of flashhavoc posts) for more updated information as it unfolds.

Comment: Sorry I meant the YN-622C not the YN-622-TX. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Hugo No worries, I've edited to match, and have thrown in what I know about the YNE3-RX units as well.