# How do I stack different brand flash controllers on my Canon 5D Mark III and still have full TTL and power control?

Tags: flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers, canon-5d-mark-iii, profoto

I am trying to control two off-camera flashes with my Canon 5D Mark III. The first flash is a Profoto B1. The other flash is a YN600EX-RT speedlight mounted on a Yongnuo YN622C II transceiver unit.

On my camera's hotshoe, I have mounted another YN622C II transceiver (to control the Yongnuo flash + YN622C II combo); on top of its pass-through hotshoe, I have mounted a Profoto AirRemote TTL-C controller (to control the Profoto B1 flash).

When I try full TTL, the Yongnuo flash seems exposed correctly, but the Profoto B1 is way overexposed. I tried setting the AirRemote TTL-C to go manual, but it keeps getting reset to TTL. I tried underexposing the B1 flash using the AirRemote TTL-C, but it keeps getting reset to full TTL and full power.

Has anyone else seen this, or have a clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are your camera's "Flash control" settings?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this question is similar (different trigger mounted on top of the older YN-622C). The comments and answers might help you figure out if this can be done, and if so, how: [Can the YN-E3-RT be used, mounted on top of the YN-622C?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/60724/11924)

Comment: Can you assign the Profoto B1 transmitter to a different group than the  YN622C II/YN600EX-RT?

Comment: Do you have HSS turned on? http://rwong2k.blogspot.com/2015/07/triggering-profoto-b1-lights-with-canon.html?m=1

Comment: Camera flash settings - flash firing enabled, e-ttl ii meter evaluative, flash sync speed in av mode auto (i was shooting manual), ettl, wireless optical, high speed sync, ch. 1, master flash firing, all groups.  hss was turned on for the profoto b1.  I'll try using different groups/channels.  I assumed (trouble) they transmitted on different frequencies and wouldn't matter.  Thanks for the responses!

Comment: After looking at settings on flashes, I did have them on different groups when shooting.  I'll try a different channel.

Comment: I tried different channels and different groups and it didn't make a difference.  I also tried setting hss off and it intermittently worked.  It was really odd, one time I turned hss off and it seemed to work.  Then I took the YN-622C ii off the hotshoe and turned off the YN-622C ii's and the YN600 and tried shooting with the ttl-c and b1 and it was shooting way overexposed.  I tried different settings and powered everything off several times.  Finally, I removed batteries on ttl-c and b1 for a minute and then ttl was working correctly again.

Comment: @shtarker Hail mary, but have you tried resetting the 622s? (btw, found an old POTN thread nearly identical to this question, where I pointed someone to that Wong post, and they said Wong emailed and said he'd returned the 622s.)

Comment: It scares me that I had to pull batteries on the ttl-c to get hss work again.  I tried changing channel and group on the 622s.  I also found I had to wiggle the 622 on the hotshoe sometimes to get it to work because it didn't fit securely.  I tried commenting on Wong's blog, but didn't get a response.  Bottom line, they scare me.

Answer (score 1):

I would in this case, mount the Yongnuo trigger on the camera to fire the speedlight.

Go grab an optical trigger and attach it to the Profoto. If you need an extension cable to make it fire, then try that.

You will have to control the B1 manually.

Or, toss the Yongnuo and get another Profoto light so you have a uniform system that can be controlled with one control unit at camera.

[image: Profoto B10 off camera flash]